# Extract specific data from webpage

Tags: c++, parsing, curl, xml-parsing, libcurl

Basically this is my code :

```
int main()
{

CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;
CURLcode res; 
std::string readBuffer;
curl = curl_easy_init(); 
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "C:\\Users\\admin\\desktop\\test.txt";
if(curl) { 
     fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com"); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=123&pass=123"); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);  

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl); 
    Sleep(1000); 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl); 
    fclose(fp);
} 

return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

The output is successfully saved in the text file.

My concern is how to extract specific content in between specific tags.

For example i want only the content between < bla> .............. < /bla> .

Whats the easiest way and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Example, you are dumping the response from the website to a file, libcURL writes the data returned by the webpage that you hit as it is, it does not take efforts for restructuring the returned data.

You can obtain the data in a memory, by defining the `write_data` function, which needs the following format only:

`size_t write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);`

Once you get the data in a memory, you can parse it and restructure it as required.
[See Example Here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) for using `write_data` function.

For XML Parsing you may use [This sample code](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/xmlstream.html)

Comment: I have it defined already , but how to get the specific content i want !

Comment: @juniorcoder Once you get data using libcurl, you are expected to parse/format it the way you need, libcurl will not do anything to it.

Check edited answer for the new link of a sample parsing, if it is useful to you.

Comment: @juniorcoder I don't think, libcurl itself does any kind of parsing/formatting to the received data or even to the data to be uploaded/sent to any server.

Comment: See this description from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html)

`Pass a char * as parameter, pointing to the full data to send in a HTTP POST operation. You must make sure that the data is formatted the way you want the server to receive it. libcurl will not convert or encode it for you in any way. For example, the web server may assume that this data is url-encoded.`

Comment: Not the perfect answer i wanted but your comments helped me alot regarding parsing issue. I'll be using Chilkat libraries to parse html as plain text then get the specific data i want after it.Thanks.